# C# wait for all threads to finish in Main()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've been coding a Multithreading Application to solve mazes. I start a new thread from my `Program Class`, `Main()` method, to begin solving the maze. He will then call a static method to create a new thread if he finds a bifurcation. How can I wait for all the threads running in the background to finish, in order to, for example display a message of completion?

This is an eskeleton of what I'm trying to do:

```
var explorer = new Explorer(/*Some arguments*/);
var thread = new Thread(explorer.Explore) {Name = "Thread 0"};
thread.Start();

//Thread_0_and_Threads_he_generates_through_static_class.Join()    

Console.WriteLine("I'm done bro.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Is there a way to do this? Honestly, first time working with Multithreading in this way, so I apologize for the poor code. Any other information I'll be more than happy to provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [Thread.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) is what you're looking for?

you also might find [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/locking.shtml) usefull.

Comment: I tried it, but it only works for the `thread 0` Thread, the other threads continue working. I get the "I'm done bro." message and then more data comes in. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jean, your question only has one thread. If you have multiple threads you must call `Join` on each one.

Comment: @DourHighArch It begins with one thread created at the `Program` Class, but as the thread works, he will invoke a static method (In another class) to create other threads to continue exploring other parts of the maze. But that is not made in the `Program` Class. So I have no way of knowing how many threads are working at a given time to call `Join()` on all of them.

Comment: @Jean, then call `Join` in the "another class".

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading is a really delighfull subject.

Since you are taking your first steps on threading, I would suggest you to carefully refer to Microsoft's [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) excelent begginers article.

Happy theading!